# Using Win 7 bootsect tool

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, bootsector

With `bootsect.exe /nt** e:` I assume, despite bootsect.exe help speaks of "master boot code", it is intended to apply the partition boostrap code to the partition identified by letter `E:`.

Given this, when the `/mbr` switch is used, are both the master boot code and the partition boot code updated or only the former?

Answer (score 0):

`bootsec` help says:

> Bootsect.exe updates the *master boot code* for hard disk partitions in order to switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR.

(Just in case) [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976786.aspx) "master boot code" definition is the standard one related to MBR:

> The MBR contains a small amount of executable code called *the master boot code*, the disk signature, and the partition table for the disk.

Based on [lifewire.com](https://www.lifewire.com/use-bootsect-nt60-to-update-the-volume-boot-code-to-bootmgr-2617975) how-to:

> Sometimes the *volume boot code*, part of the *volume boot record* that resides on the drive that Windows is installed on, can become corrupt or accidentally reprogrammed to use the wrong boot manager. [...]
>   Luckily, correcting *volume boot code* errors is easy with the bootsect command, a *boot sector restore tool* only available from the Command Prompt.
>   [...]
>   At the prompt, type the bootsect command as shown below and then press Enter:

```
bootsect /nt60 sys
```

See also [terabyteunlimited.com](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=556):

> When the Windows system (booting) *partition's boot sector* is corrupted or otherwise contains invalid code for the version of Windows on the partition, it must be repaired before the *partition* will boot properly. [...]  the *boot sector* can be updated manually by using the `bootsect.exe` program.

The *master boot sector* is never mentioned, because by default the command fixes the *partition boot sector*, otherwise told *volume boot sector*, so the [VBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) and not the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record). Therefore **Microsoft documentation should be fixed** too, removing the word 'master': "Bootsect.exe updates the boot code for hard disk partitions".

Of course, the default behaviour can be changed and have the tool acting on the MBR too, and this is the reason why the `/mbr` switch exists.